# Social Tables: Does Layout Automation for Theatre support specific number of aisles/columns?

Tags: social-tables

Does the Layout Automation endpoint support the ability to precisely control the number of vertical aisles or columns through the API? There are circumstances where we many want to include specifically one or two aisles in a diagram.

Currently, it seems that the number of vertical aisles is interpolated depending on the aisles.vertical.floorElementsBetween.width value, the attendees value and the room geometry.

For example, sometimes when just the aisle.vertical.width is decreased,
the number of columns will change automatically from one to two or three aisles/columns (even if floorElementsBetween and all other paramters remain constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Layout Automation API endpoint does not currently allow precise control of the number of columns or rows for any setup types.